# Finding a full roster and history for the US Army's Philippine-American war veterans?

Tags: military-records, philippines

Where can I find a full roster and history for the US Army's 38th Volunteer Infantry, Company L, Philippine-American war veterans?

The article [Philippine–American War](https://www.geni.com/projects/Philippine-American-War/25269) on Geni explains why researching soldiers in this particular war is so difficult, particularly in the later units.

> "At the time that the Spanish American War ended, only the 1st through
> the 10th U.S. Volunteer Infantry regiments existed. His regiment, the
> 38th U.S. Volunteer Infantry, was formed later for service in the
> Philippines.
>
> The Spanish American War lasted from April to December 10, 1898, when
> the Treaty of Paris was signed, ending the war. On February 4, 1899,
> war broke out betwen the U.S. and its former defacto ally, the
> Filipinos. This conflict lasted into 1902, but fighting actually
> continued until 1913 in some areas.
>
> A pension fund was created for the Spanish American War, but not for
> the Philippine American War or the Chinese Relief Expedition ("Boxer
> Rebellion"). As a result, to allow men to receive pensions, the
> government lumped veterans of all three conflicts together, calling
> them Spanish American War Veterans....though they may have joined the
> military 15 years after the war ended or fought in China! This
> designation will appear on all government documents, including
> government-issued gravestones. From the unit designation, however, we
> can tell where and when he fought (Philippines, probably 1899 to
> 1902). He is not, unless he served in a different regiment earlier, an
> actual Spanish American War Veteran."

My granduncle mustered into 'L' Company of the 38th Volunteer Infantry during September of 1899.  Prior to service, he resided in Michigan, and his enlistment records indicate Cascade County, Montana, where he spent most of his life.

His military records, headstone, and headstone application all indicate this same information (with the exception of being exactly 1-month off on his muster-in date) for his service, but I cannot find a history page, roster, etc. for his infantry division or 'L' Company.

Comment: I've moved your full title into the body of the Q and shortened the title so it will display more cleanly when shared (e.g. on Twitter).  I've also added the title of the article you linked to on Geni so it will be clear which article you meant.  If a community member has already read that article, they can see which one you are linking to and get on with answering your question, without having to stop and see what the linked article is.